# CompletableFuture from ExecutorService

Tags: java, executorservice, completable-future

I have created a custom `ExecutorService`

```
ExecutorService executor =
        new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, maxPoolSize, keepAliveTime, timeUnit,
                               new LinkedBlockingDeque<>());
```

to which I submit my tasks

```
Future<String> result = executor.submit(() -> "test");
```

As you can see, the executor returns a meager `Future`; I'd much rather have a [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) that I can chain with other `CompletableFuture`s.

In [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), we have the [`ListeningExecutorService`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListeningExecutorService.java) that returns [`ListenableFuture`s](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained). Those `ListenableFuture`s are, for my intents and purposes, as nice as `CompletableFuture`s.

Still, I'd like to use Java's standard library as much as possible which means I'm looking for a way to get `CompletableFuture`s from my custom executor.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In hindsight it's obvious: Don't try to get a `CompletableFuture` from the executor, instead, pass the executor to the `CompletableFuture`.

Like this:

```
CompletableFuture<String> futureOutput =
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "test", executor);
```

The task will be executed using one of the threads provided by `executor` and clients have all the conveniences of `CompletableFuture` to get at the task's result.

Comment: You can also use Executors.newFixedThreadPool() or Executors.newCachedThreadPool() instead of executor

Comment: CompletableFuture<String> futureOutput =
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "test", Executors.newCachedThreadPool());